# Xamarin/Visual Studio 2015 - Should I use sqlite and query issues,

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

New to Xamarin and c# but I'm trying to make a really simple app for my class that searches a database for an ingredient and returns the nutritional info. My group knows python so they wrote the code out in that and I'm trying to make as simple of an app as I can just for show, but I'm having some trouble. We took the USDA database as a download from their website and he data in the file is in

"NDB_No,Shrt_Desc,Energ_Kcal,Protein_g,Lipid_Tot_g,Ash_g,Carbohydrt_g,Fiber_TD_g,Sugar_Tot_g,Calcium_mg,Iron_mg,Magnesium_mg,Phosphorus_mg,Potassium_mg,Sodium_mg,Zinc_mg,Copper_mg,Manganese_mg,Selenium_ug,Vit_C_mg,Thiamin_mg,Riboflavin_mg,Niacin_mg,Panto_Acid_mg,Vit_B6_mg,Folate_Tot_ug,Folic_Acid_ug,Food_Folate_ug,Folate_DFE_ug,Choline_Tot_ mg,Vit_B12_ug,Vit_A_IU,Vit_A_RAE,Retinol_ug,Alpha_Carot_ug,Beta_Carot_ug,Beta_Crypt_ug,Lycopene_ug,Lut+Zea_ ug,Vit_E_mg,Vit_D_ug,Vit_D_IU,Vit_K_ug,FA_Sat_g,FA_Mono_g,FA_Poly_g,Cholestrl_mg,Gm_unit,num,unit"

format with several hundred ingredients. Such as

"1145,BUTTER,717,0.85,81.11,0.09,0.06,0,0.06,24,0.02,2,24,24,11,0.09,0.016,0.004,1,0,0.005,0.034,0.042,0.11,0.003,3,0,3,3,18.8,0.17,2499,684,671,0,158,0,0,0,2.32,0,0,7,50.489,23.43,3.01,215,5,1,tbsp"

They used sqlite3 to make a table and query it in Python, just using c.fetchrow to return a line of data and an array to divide it up. That code can be found here: https://github.com/pjomara/SoftwareEngineeringIIProject/blob/master/nutr_data_grabber.py

I can't find any good examples and don't need to create a database, just read from the one I have.
I'm stuck and any help, example code or such would be awesome. Thanks

The current error is "
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SQLite.TableQuery' to 'int' nutr_grabber    C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\nutr_grabber\nutr_grabber\MainActivity.cs  53  Active"

```
namespace nutr_grabber
{
    [Activity(Label = "nutr_grabber", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    string str1;

    private static string DB_PATH = "/data/data/nutr_grabber/databases/";

    private static string DB_NAME = "UsdDataProto.db";

    private void copyDataBase()
    {
        var dbInput = ApplicationContext.Assets.Open(DB_NAME);
        string dbProto = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        var myOutput = new FileStream(dbProto, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = dbInput.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
            myOutput.Write(buffer, 0, length);
        myOutput.Flush();
        myOutput.Close();
        dbInput.Close();
    }


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        //set widgets
        TextView message = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message);
        EditText ingred = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.enterHere);
        Button search = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.search);

        string proto = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath();
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine( proto , "UsdDataProto.db"));
        db.CreateTable<usdProto>();



        search.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            str1 = ingred.Text;



            var Item = db.Query<usdProto>("SELECT Energ_Kcal FROM usdProto WHERE Shrt_Desc = ?", str1);



              new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
              .SetMessage(Item)
              .Show();


        };



    }
}



public class usdProto
{
    [PrimaryKey]

    public int NDB_No { get; set; }
    public string Shrt_Desc { get; set; }
    public int Energ_Kcal { get; set; }
    public int Protein_g { get; set; }
    public int Lipid_Tot_g { get; set; }
    public int Ash_g { get; set; }
    public int Carbohydrt_g { get; set; }
```

Comment: there are many, many samples, walkthroughs, etc on using sqlite with Xamarin.  I'd try reading them and then if you have a specific question or issues, ask about that.  For example, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_5_using_data_in_an_app/#Using_a_pre-populated_SQLite_database_file

Comment: I searched for so long and the one thing I didn't find would have been useful. I actually got it able to read a line just from opening the file using
streamreader.
Any advice on how to search the file for something, like "butter" then return the line? All I have right now is just ReadLine(), which, as you can guess, only returns the first line.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of problem databases were designed to solve.

Comment: I've been trying, but the database isn't really working for me. Is there a way to just search the file and get the line?

Comment: read every line until you find the one that you want

Comment: I think I got the database working. How do I go about a query if someone enters "butter" and I store that as str1 ?

Comment: var query = conn.Table<MyTableName>().Where (v => v.MyColumnName.Contains("butter"));

Comment: I pretty much had that, but is there a certain way to output it? When I try a dialog alert and have .SetMessage(query) I have an error that says  " Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SQLite.TableQuery<nutr_grabber.usdProto>' to 'int' nutr_grabber C:\Users\Steve\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\nutr_grabber\nutr_grabber\MainActivity.cs  52  Active"

Comment: your query is returning (potentially) multiple rows and multiple columns of data, not just one single value.

Comment: I'll just throw my code up, there's not a lot which is why this is so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

your query is going to return an IEnumerable of objects, in your case usdProto:

```
var query = db.Table<usdProto>().Where(v => v.Shrt_Desc.Contains(str1));

foreach (var item in query) {
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .SetMessage(item.SomeProperty)
            .Show();
}
```

replace SomeProperty with whichever property of usdProto that you want to display

Comment: I have no error, but nothing happens. Did I do the usdProto Class wrong?

Comment: are you sure that your table has data in it?

Comment: based on your code,  you are creating and empty db and creating an empty table in it, instead of opening an existing db that is embedded in your app

Comment: My dB definitely has data in it. Maybe I tried opening it wrong, it's just a file in my assets folder.

Comment: your are creating a blank db in Personal, not opening an existing assets file

Comment: I tried searching for how to go about opening an existing database and all i could find is copying it from the assets folder. I tried implementing the code do that and, I still have the error that " cannot convert Item to Int", any ideas?

Also I really appreciate the help.

Comment: this sounds like a new question to me

Comment: Any idea why it still wont connect though?

Comment: please post a new question and include the necessary details about the current problem you're having (copying a db from Assets and opening it)